# Prevent automatic paged URL redirection in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have WordPress 5.1 installed and permalinks structure **enabled**.
So the links have this structure: `http://example.com/taxonomy_name/term-slug`

However, I have created a custom paginator which has links like: `http://example.com/taxonomy_name/?order=ASC&orderby=title&taxonomy_2=term-slug` and it works fine. So when I click this URL it stays not modified.

But if it has a page argument like this: `http://example.com/taxonomy_name/?order=ASC&orderby=title&taxonomy_2=term-slug&paged=X` *(**X** can be any number)* then when I click this URL it automatically redirects me to: `http://example.com/taxonomy_name/page/X/?order=ASC&orderby=title&taxonomy_2=term-slug`

How to prevent **only** this paginator redirection?

Comment: Where is the code?Blind shot - rename ```paged```var?

Comment: @Sky which code? There is no code. Only the links. The question is how to prevent the redirection.

Comment: Rename ```paged``` var

Comment: And? It will not work without additional coding to pass new var to the query.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by creating a filter for WP built-in canonical redirect rules.

This is the filter function:

```
function disable_paged_canonical_redirect($redirect_url, $requested_url){
    // Retrieve paged var from $_GET request
    $page_num = (int)filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'paged');
    // Check if there is a canonical '/page/X' part in the URL.
    $canonical_paged = preg_match('/\/page\/[0-9]+/i', $redirect_url);
    // If paged var is in GET vars and WP created canonical redirect for it, then revert this change.
    if( $canonical_paged && $page_num ){
        // Remove page part from canonical URL
        $redirect_url = preg_replace('/\/page\/[0-9]+/i','', $redirect_url);
        // Add paged var to URL arguments
        $redirect_url .= '&paged='.$page_num;
    }
    return $redirect_url;
}
add_filter('redirect_canonical','disable_paged_canonical_redirect', 10, 2);
```